# C# custom XML tags with WriteXML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am creating XML file from DataSet, But there are three problems,

1) I want to assign custom tag name of table from < table > to < my_items > 
2) I dont understand Minus (-) sign on before starting of some tags ? 
3) I want to create XSL file with it as well is it possible with .WriteXML ?

C# Code:

```
string connectionString = @"Connection string";           
    using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
       using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from items", _con))
       {            
          DataSet ds = new DataSet("oitm");
          SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
          _con.Open();
          _dap.Fill(ds);
          ds.WriteXml("test.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
          _con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Output file (test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
-<oitm>

    -<xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas_microsoft_com:xml_msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" id="oitm">
    -<xs:element msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="oitm">
        -<xs:complexType>
          -<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            -<xs:element name="Table">
              -<xs:complexType>
                -<xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ItemCode" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="ItemName" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="LastPurPrc" minOccurs="0" type="xs:decimal"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>

    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    -<Table>
         <ItemCode>0004</ItemCode>
         <ItemName>Realisierung FP</ItemName>
         <LastPurPrc>0.000000</LastPurPrc>
    </Table>
    -<Table>
         <ItemCode>0005</ItemCode>
         <ItemName>km-Geld</ItemName>
         <LastPurPrc>0.000000</LastPurPrc>
     </Table>
</oitm>
```

Comment: As presented, the output file is not well-formed XML on account of having non-whitespace text outside the root element.  But are you sure this is the actual XML?  It looks like a screen-scrape of an XML editor's presentation of the file, with the `-` signs being buttons / links for collapsing the representation of the associated element.  (I.e., I suspect the `-` signs are not part of the actual XML.)

Comment: your comment voted up!... i figured out minus Signs because of you, i have copied it to understand so there are white spaces and minus signs ... :)... what about remaning two issues ?

Comment: I am not prepared to answer your other questions, but Microsoft appears to have considerable documentation for `DataSet` and related classes available online.